# Access VBA to Pass Parameter To Report Based On Query

Tags: ms-access, vba, report, ms-access-2013

I am close on having syntax accurate, just one big problem!

The User ID that I am capturing from the input box, is not being passed into the report, so I have to input the user id twice

What needs to be altered in order to achieve this?

```
Public Function userProd() As Integer
Dim userID As String, saveloc As String, filename As String, reportname As String

'Report Name
reportname = "rpt_UserProduction"

'Setting Save location
saveloc = "C:\Test\"

'Setting filename
filename = "userProd "

'Getting User ID To Process
userID = InputBox("Enter User ID:", "VBA InputBox Function")

'Putting together full save location
saveloc = saveloc + filename + userID + ".pdf"

If userID = "" Then
    'Do Nothing and Stop Processing
    Exit Function
Else
    If IsNumeric(userID) Then
        'Preview Report
        DoCmd.OpenReport reportname, acViewPreview, , "User_ID=" & userID

        'Save As PDF
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportname, acFormatPDF, saveloc, True

        'Close Report
        DoCmd.Close acReport, reportname
    End If
End If

End Function
```

Comment: The `Return` statement is for use with [`GoSub`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251648.aspx), you probably mean to use `Exit Function`.

Comment: @ThunderFrame - good catch on that syntax mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Is the User_ID field a text field that holds a number?  If so, you need to add single quotes to the filter.  ... "User_ID='" & userId & "'".  If it's not text, are you getting too many records or not enough? Is there another filter being applied when the report loads, or in the underlying report record source that is causing the filter to not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

If "twice" means once for the inputbox and once for the report, then `"User_ID="` in your where condition is either misspelled or excluded from the query you use as source for the report.